# Trouble using Shell Command with a Variable in File Path within VB

Tags: vb.net, shell, vb.net-2010, rdp

This is probably a simple fix or totally impossible......not entirely sure....

I have a database stored remotely and my program accesses it. It has a list of properties that we do remote support for. There is a folder full of RDP's as well. When I use the code below it works BUT when I switch the path to a variable it does not. I tried converting to different things and it still say the path does not exist.

I tried calling the variable to display in a messagebox to verify the data in the string is correct and it is.

THIS WORKS
 Shell("C:\Windows\System32\mstsc.exe P:\Server\program\Server.RDP", vbMaximizedFocus)

THIS DOES NOT BUT THIS IS WHAT I NEED

Shell("C:\Windows\System32\mstsc.exe" & RDPtext.Text, vbMaximizedFocus)

RDPText.text is a label that is displaying info from the database. That info is the file path. I tried creating a variable and passing the string to the variable with no luck either.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For further explanation the program allows the user to select a Porperty. All of the Property's info is displayed and I have an image that when clicked is supposed to open the RDP but obviously the path changes as the Property does. Hardcoding select case statements is not an option. It needs to pull the path from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second example you didn't add the required space betweeen the exe and its argument

```
 Shell("C:\Windows\System32\mstsc.exe " & RDPtext.Text, vbMaximizedFocus)
                                     ^
```

Comment: That's it! WOW! Stupid mistake. Thanks so much for the quick response!

Comment: @DaveyLions plz check off his answer if it helped

Comment: I dont see anywhere to "check off" the answer. At least on my phone. I tried to upvote but it wont let me because my rep is not high enough